# Is there a ruby gem that will easily "pretty print" Date objects to words? (i.e. 01-01-2001 to "January 1, 2001", etc)

Tags: ruby, date, rubygems, pretty-print

I'm writing a ruby script whose purpose is generating contracts. It is very simple to implement. I just load up a bunch of variables and input those into a big string all at once like so:

```
outputstring = <<-eos
 #{Time.now.to_date.to_s}
 ...

eos
```

It has a bunch of other fancy words after the date, but I want the date to be something like: "January 1st, 2015". I could manually implement all of this noise, but I'm thinking there has got to be a gem that will quickly handle this task for me. I see gems like `number_in_words` and have to wonder..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be a gem?

What about this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Time.now.strftime("%B %-d, %Y")
 => "August 7, 2014"
```

and/or

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Time.parse("2015-01-01").to_date.strftime("%B %-d, %Y")
 => "January 1, 2015"
```

(you might have to `require 'time'` for the second example

Comment: it should be, but nice answer dude. Honestly, I may develop the damn gem. It should be called `pretty_print_date` and just do that. Thanks.

Comment: @boulder_ruby OK, you might want to look into ActiveSupport's http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s which can be included into non-Rails environments...